# How to fix a corrupt *.ts file

Tags: video, file-corruption, error-correction

sorry for my bad english but I hope you understand my question.

I have a 18GB Transport Stream file which seems to be corrupt. Therefore it is not possible to upload this file to Youtube. Now I hope somebody of you can help me. Maybe it is possible to cut out the damaged parts or to recover the whole file. For better analysis here the output from the "ffprobe" command (Windows 10)

```
ffprobe.exe -i z:\mario\Video.ts

ffprobe version 2021-01-27-git-149bfc2445-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 64.100 / 56. 64.100
  libavcodec     58.119.100 / 58.119.100
  libavformat    58. 65.101 / 58. 65.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7. 98.100 /  7. 98.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000197fa177a80] no frame!
[mpegts @ 00000197fa15ac00] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 00000197fa15ac00] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 7475501244).
Input #0, mpegts, from 'z:\mario\Video.ts':
  Duration: 04:50:35.30, start: 65626.756933, bitrate: 9617 kb/s
  Program 25114
  Program 25115
  Program 41104
  Program 44106
  Program 44107
    Stream #0:0[0x233]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x234](deu): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
  Program 44108
```

Then I have created an `error.log` file with the following command

```
ffmpeg.exe -v error -i z:\mario\Video.ts -f null - >error.log 2>&1
```

The log file is saved on the following Google drive.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PCrvstWkZtisyCn-AWqgFjPjBOYEidK5/view?usp=sharing

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Who produced the video? If its made by someone other than yourself maybe someone has saved a copy?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing such a problem requires specialized software.

Below are some such products:

- [ProjectX](https://www.videohelp.com/software/ProjectX) :
  Old software but may still work (free)
- [Video Repair Tool](https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/video-repair/)
  (commercial with trial)
- [Stellar Photo Recovery Professional](https://www.rescuedigitalmedia.com/video-recovery)
  (commercial with trial)

I haven't used any of these tools and cannot give my personal recommendation
for one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have hoped to repair the file with ffmpeg. A split of the file is acceptable for me too. Or is it in case of a transport stream not repairable?

Comment: ffprobe had a problem and stopped at MB 62, which doesn't seem like much for a video. ffmpeg might not be able to do better.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean at MB 62 ? at 62 MByte ? Where do have identify this position? Then I could cut the video with e.g. Xmedia Recode at 5 or 10 minutes and would not loose the whole file.

Comment: At the very end of the log file.